# Javascript - Regexes and lazyness

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that will match strings that contain the substring "abc", but not the substrings "abcdef" or "abcghi". The best solution I could find was this:

```
/^.*abc(?!def|ghi).*$/i
```

However, this wronlgy matches the following string:

```
xxxabcxabcdefxx
```

My regex is fooled by the apparition of the "abcx" string, witch contains "abc" that is not followed by the forbidden suffixes.
I have tried using the "+" and "?" modifiers to no avail.

I think I could work around this by using a regex with no wildcards, and comparing the matched string with the full string, but I find that solution to seem kind of.. patched.

Comment: Apply the lookahead to the whole string. `/^(?!.*abc(?:def|ghi)).*abc.*$/`

Comment: This seems to do the job just right, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not search for strings that don't contain the strings abcdef and abcghi:

```
.*(abcdef|abcghi).*
```

and exclude those?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = 'xxxabcxabcdefxx';
if (/abc(?:def|ghi)/g.test(a))
 console.log( /^.*(abc(?:def|ghi)).*/g.exec(a))
```